# How can I stop JLabel scaling an image?

Tags: java, swing, java-9, image-scaling, highdpi

I have a Swing app that can display an image by loading it into a `JLabel`. Up to Java 8, this worked fine. Since Java 9 there are changes intended to make apps resize on higher pixel densities, including rescaling images: when pixel density is high, images are scaled up. The results are ugly in many cases. As an example, if I have a photo with a high pixel count, my app scales it down to fit the available space, but then it's automatically scaled back up to allow for the higher pixel density - ugly.

A couple of options I can see for avoiding this problem are:

1. Implementing the interface `java.awt.image.MultiResolutionImage` which looks like it should help, but I don't see how to use that with `JLabel`.
2. Maybe there's a way to fool Swing into thinking that no pixel scaling is necessary, but I can't find anything like that

The following code is a simple example of displaying an image in a label. In Java 8, the image is displayed pixel-for-pixel. In Java 9+, the whole UI including the image is scaled up according to what your OS thinks  is your pixel density. You should be able to set this scaling explicitly - Windows 10 has it under "Display", "Scale and Layout". Mine is set to 125% which seems to be a perfect amount to make almost any image look ugly.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Img extends JFrame {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        new Img( new File( args[0] ) );
    }

    private Img( File file ) throws IOException {
        super( "Img: " + file.getName () );
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon( ImageIO.read( file ) );
        JLabel label = new JLabel( img );
        label.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight() ) );
        add( label );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        pack();
        setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: *if I have a photo with a high pixel count, my app scales it down to fit the available space* - Check out the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). It will dynamically scale. I see the same size image whether using 100% or 150%. That is the image fills the screen either way. Of course if the image is smaller than the screen, then I still do get the upscaling issues.